# np.linalg.norm on multiple rows in array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the magnitude of each vector in an array that looks like this ;

```
[[0.1,1.0,2.0]
[0.5,2.0,1.0]
[0.4,3.0,0.5]]
```

I want to put these into a new numpy array like this ;

```
[[1.2]
[2.0]
[2.1]]
```

Currently i'm doing this with a loop;

```
for i in range(x)):
    d = vec2[i] - vec1[i]
    dist[i] = np.linalg.norm(d)
```

However i'd like to do this with pure numpy ( the above are numpy arrays)
Is there a way i'm missing to do this on a single line?
This does not work, as the values I get are not identical;

```
d = vec2 - vec1
dist = np.linalg.norm(d, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use axis=0 or axis=1, that should perform the calculation over each array, depending the direction your going

Comment: Using axis=0 gives a result for each column eg -
[1.5 , 2 , 3] 
using axis=1 gives an odd result, that when reshaped has incorrect values. I'll update question with a test.